# How do I get friend list from Friends table with counts of friends of my friends

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

How do I get friend list from Friends table with counts of friends of my friends (Count not of my friends)

Friends table"
tbl_users_friends

Field 1: id 
Field 2: user_id 
Field 3: friend_user_id

and I need the out put as:

A has following friedns:

x (10)
y (2)
z (0)

Above is the list of my friends and in parenthesis contains their friends count.

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that user A has a friend B, but B has not a friend A? In other words: Is it possible that a friend of mine has no friends (not even me)?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel `z (0)` in the question says that it's possible, i think

Comment: @splash58 you are right, i think :-)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yes, you are right

Answer (score 2):

```
select user_id, count(*) cnt 
   from  Friends 
   where user_id in  
      (select friend_user_id 
         from Friends 
         where user_id = user_id_of_A)
   group by user_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but Sorry, it is not working as expecting

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```sql
select u.user_id, u.name, count(uf1.id) as num_friends
from tbl_users_friends uf
inner join tbl_users u           on u.user_id = uf.friend_user_id
left  join tbl_users_friends uf1 on uf1.user_id = uf.friend_user_id
where uf.user_id = 1
group by u.user_id, u.name
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10033/1

You need to ajust the users table and column names.

Another solution with a subselect but without group by:

```sql
select u.user_id, u.name, (
        select count(*)
        from tbl_users_friends uf1
        where uf1.user_id = uf.friend_user_id
    ) as num_friends
from tbl_users_friends uf
inner join tbl_users u on u.user_id = uf.friend_user_id
where uf.user_id = 1
```